# How to stop diagonalFade if I move the mouse very quickly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I have the following code but if I move the mouse really quickly, the images still fade in&out constantly.

`stop()` works if I use `animate()` but when I use this plugin it doesn't.

```
$('.person a').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $($(this).children('.overstate')).stop().diagonalFade({
    time: 350,
    fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
    fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
    fade: 'out'
    });
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $($(this).children('.overstate')).stop().diagonalFade({
    time: 350,
    fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
    fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
    fade: 'in'
    });
});
```

html

```
                <div class="person">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/p1h.jpg" />
                        <span class="name">Lee</span>
                        <span class="overstate">
                            <img src="images/p1.jpg" />                         
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div><!--end person-->
```

css

```
.person { float:left; width:180px; margin-bottom:40px; height:236px; margin-right:31px; }
    .lastperson { margin-right:0; }
.person a { display:block; width:180px; height:236px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.person img { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
.name { display:block; width:170px; height:34px; background:url(../images/team-name.png) no-repeat top left; font-size:18px; color:#FFF; text-align:left; line-height:33px; padding-left:10px; float:left; position:relative; z-index:5000;}
.overstate { left:0; top:0; position:absolute; z-index:3000;  }
```

I thought that something like that might work but keeps flashing if I move the mouse over a couple of times

```
$('.person a').live('mouseenter', function() {
  if (!$(this).children('.overstate').hasClass('animated')) {

     $($(this).children('.overstate')).stop().diagonalFade({
     time: 450,
     fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
     fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
     fade: 'out'
    });

  }
  }).live('mouseleave', function() {
      $($(this).children('.overstate')).addClass('animated').stop().diagonalFade({
      time: 450,
      fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
      fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
      fade: 'in',
      complete: function() { $('.person a').children('.overstate').removeClass('animated'); }
 });
```

});

Comment: and the css please, your entire code

Comment: When I mouseover then span.overstate gets opacity:0 with the plugin diagonalFade and <img src="images/p1h.jpg" /> is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid that the single solution cand be something like this:

```
    <script>
    var inactive = 1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.person a').live('mouseenter', function(e) {
            if(inactive==1){
                inactive = 0;
                $($(this).children('.overstate')).stop().diagonalFade({
                time: 350,
                fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
                fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
                fade: 'out',
                complete:function(){
                    inactive=1; 
                }

                });
            }
        })
        $('.person a').live('mouseleave', function() {

                inactive = 0;
                $($(this).children('.overstate')).stop().diagonalFade({
                time: 350,
                fadeDirection_x: 'left-right',
                fadeDirection_y: 'top-bottom',
                fade: 'in',
                complete: function(){
                inactive=1; 

                }
            });

        });
})

</script>
```

Comment: Can the inactive flag be unique for each .person a? Because is isn't working when I go from a person a to another and I believe there is the problem

Comment: Nikos, you can use $(".person a").data("inactive", 1), or $(".person a").data("inactive") to retrieve it if you want to keep a flag for each .person.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery tip:  `$($(this).children('.overstate')).stop()` is redundant.  You can just call `$(this).children('.overstate').stop()`.